# More convenient JOOQ custom types definition

Tags: java, sql, maven, jooq

We are using `JOOQ` with quite a big amount of custom types, and our "jooq-codegen-maven" config section is huge, and annoys me in `pom.xml`.

It would be good to have this config in separate file. Is it possible in a some way?

Answer (score 0):

That certainly makes sense and will be covered in [feature request #4163](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4163). I'm not aware of a way to partially externalise Maven plugin configurations, though...